# Using nestedset in Laravel to design a nested treant tree

Tags: php, laravel, nested

I'm trying to figure out how these nestedsets in Laravel works. I've an many to many relation between `organizations` and `departments`. An `organization` can have many `departments`. An department can have many `departments`. For this I'm using [Nestedsets](https://github.com/lazychaser/laravel-nestedset).

What I'm trying to do, is retrieving all organizations from a user. On this query I'd like to retrieve all departments attached to these organizations. I'd like the structure, so I've a infinite parent -> child relation on my departments, so I'm able to build a structuretree using [treant.js](https://fperucic.github.io/treant-js/).

I'm pretty sure I've everything build correctly in my database, so my first thought were to use `with`. However it seems like I'm only getting the first children. Here is an example:

```
$currentUser->organizations()->with(
            'departments.children',
            'departments.commodities',
            'departments.children.commodities',
        )->get()
```

I've to include children.[model] for every nested department. So if I've two levels, I've to add departments.children.children.commodities, and so on. This seems pretty retarded!

I've been trying pretty many different approches to get a proper solution, but the one below is my best solution for now. I just feel like I'm using the nestedset-library wrong.

```
public function getUserDepartmentTree() {
    foreach ( $this->organizations()->get() as $organization ) {
        $dep[] = $organization->departments()->get()->toTree();
    }

    return $dep;
}
```

So my question is, how should I get all relational data from my departments tree-structured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you'll want to use `descendants` instead of `children` as `children` will only return the direct/first child models whereas `descendants` will return everything under a certain node.

Since this will add the relationship as `descendants` instead of children you'll need to tweak it slightly i.e. change the name of the relationship and then use the `toTree()` method:

```
$organizations = $currentUser->organizations()
    ->with('departments.commodities', 'departments.descendants.commodities')
    ->get()
    ->map(function ($organization) {
        $organization->departments->map(function ($department) {
            return $department->setRelation('children', $department->descendants->toTree())->unsetRelation('descendants');
        });

        return $organization;
    });
```